How to derive the deformation matrix $F$ of axisymmetric problem?
I am working on a 2D axisymmetric problem and am wondering how to derive the gradient operation matrix for an element and the deformation matrix, I have no clue how to do it and after searching on the internet I only find the derivation of axisymmetric strain matrix but then I don't know how to proceed

The derivation of the deformation matrix can be seen in deformation matrix
then for the derivation of symmetric gradient matrix and spatial matrix, note that we can write any displacement and test function in axisymmetric case as $d=u(r,z)e_r+v(r,z)e_z$, in which there is no $\theta$, then for a vector in cylinder coordinate $A=A_{\rho} \hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}+A_{\varphi}\hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}}+A_{z}\hat{\mathbf{z}}$, we can write the gradient of this vector as
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \frac{\partial A_\rho}{\partial \rho} \hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}} \otimes \hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}+\left(\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial A_\rho}{\partial \varphi}-\frac{A_{\varphi}}{\rho}\right) \hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}} \otimes \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}}+\frac{\partial A_\rho}{\partial z} \hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}} \otimes \hat{\mathbf{z}} \\
+ & \frac{\partial A_{\varphi}}{\partial \rho} \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}} \otimes \hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}+\left(\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial A_{\varphi}}{\partial \varphi}+\frac{A_\rho}{\rho}\right) \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}} \otimes \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}}+\frac{\partial A_{\varphi}}{\partial z} \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}} \otimes \hat{\mathbf{z}} \\
+ & \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial \rho} \hat{\mathbf{z}} \otimes \hat{\boldsymbol{\rho}}+\frac{1}{\rho} \frac{\partial A_z}{\partial \varphi} \hat{\mathbf{z}} \otimes \hat{\boldsymbol{\varphi}}+\frac{\partial A_z}{\partial z} \hat{\mathbf{z}} \otimes \hat{\mathbf{z}}
\end{aligned}
$$
then we put $d$ inside and notice that $d_{\varphi}=0$, we can hence get the spatial gradient matrix and symmetric gradient matrix
